# Getting chance percentage

Tags: android

I want to display some images by chance. I know how to display images but how to get their chance of displaying?

For example let's say that the first image from 100% chance of displaying it has only a probability of 0.01% of displaying, the second 1.20%, third 15.00% and soo on.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use a random number generator. Depending on the generated number decide which image to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 double[] chances = {1, 35, 0.85, 50, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001, 65, 11};
Random r = new Random();
boolean dropped = false;
for (int i = 0; i < chances.length; i++) {
    if (chances[i] > r.nextDouble() * 100) {
        System.out.println("Item with " + chances[i] + " chance is dropped");
        dropped = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (dropped == false) {
    System.out.println("Dropping default item");
}
```